# Not able to print the value of a key of a Map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm fairly new to Kotlin. I want to print the count of a character in a string. For this, I'm using Kotlin's `groupingBy()` function and applying `eachCount()` to it.

My code:

```
val str = "0100101101010"
val countMap : Map<Char, Int> = str.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
println(countMap["1"])
```

But I'm getting this error in the console: `Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter K should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.`

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"1"` is a *string* literal, but your map has *characters* as keys. You should use the *character* literal `'1'`:

```
println(countMap['1'])
```

The reason for that confusing error message is because it is trying to call [this `get` overload](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get.html), which is generic. It tries to infer the generic type arguments, and fails.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks. I'm still trying to figure out how could I be so naive.