# TypeVariable(V) Required in Mutable Map assignment in Kotlin. Cannot put the value from a map to itself

Tags: kotlin

The following example is a simplified version of what I am trying to do in my application.

```
fun main() {
    val test: MutableMap<Int, String> = mutableMapOf(
        1 to "Apple",
    )
    test[2] = test[1]  // test[1] has incorrect type.
}
```

The code doesn't compile. IntelliJ gives the following hint:

```
Type mismatch.

    Required:   TypeVariable(V)

    Found:      String?
```

I don't understand what a TypeVariable is. but when I provide a default value the error disappears

```
test[2] = test[1] ?: "Grape"
```

Why the required type is `TypeVariable(V)`, not `String`, and what exactly is it? What to do if there's no default value for my application purposes?

Comment: You understand why `test[1] ?: "Grape"` works, but just don't understand the error message, right? The compiler is trying to infer the `V` type parameter for [this `set` method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set.html). See this very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70910088/5133585) about incorrectly accessing a map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
... = test[1]
```

returns a String? as the hint showed you. But *test* is a MutableMap of <Int, String>, which means you need to assign a String:

```
... = test[1]!!
```

Of course this will only work if 1 is a valid key in *test*. Otherwise your code with the null safety operator is the way to go:

```
... = test[1] ?: "default value"
```